# what is char (*var)[6] and char* var[6]?

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

I am reading bit masks on learnCpp.com: [bit-manipulation-with-bitwise-operators-and-bit-masks](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/bit-manipulation-with-bitwise-operators-and-bit-masks)
and encountered this line:

```
constexpr std::uint_fast8_t mask0{ 0b0000'0001 };
```

I forget what constexpr means, probably forgot it for a million times already lol. so I went to see what it is through cppreference.com:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr

The reading was difficult, so I try to understand through the example on that website, and I see this strange parameter type in a constructor(`N` is a known template non-type parameter):

```
constexpr conststr(const char(&a)[N]): p(a), sz(N - 1) {}
```

So what exactly is this:

```
char(&a)[N]
```

Comment: i would say _const reference to a char array of size N_

Comment: @Berto99 A reference to an array of N const chars. A "const reference" is not a thing.